# Two-dimensional string pointer

Tags: c, c-strings

In the process of debugging this procedure, I found two-dimensional behind the target can not add NULL.

```
void list_dir(char **dirp_array)
{
    char *dir_name = "./";
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;

    if ((dp = opendir((const char *)dir_name)) == NULL){
        perr_exit("opendir errno");
    }

    while((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL){
        (* dirp_array) = strdup((char *)dirp->d_name);
        printf("%s\n",(* dirp_array));
        dirp_array ++;
        //dirp_array += strlen(*dirp_array);
    }
    *dirp_array = NULL;
    closedir(dp);
}
```

after modify，i want to get the two-dimensionalh which i have defined.
so, i define a function here.

```
void chack_array(char **array)
{
    while(array != NULL){
        printf("%s\n",(* array));
        array ++;
    }
}

main(){
    char *dirp_array[256];
    list_dir(dirp_array);
    chack_array(dirp_array);
}
```

but i core dump

Comment: while i can't get the NULL flags,i mean i wil can't stop.

Comment: You should state what language you're using and make the code more readable.

Comment: ok,i know ,i should modify **while(array != NULL)** for **while(*array != NULL)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
dirp_array = NULL;
```

Should be

```
*dirp_array = NULL;
```

Your first version does not change contents of the array provided by caller. It just says that the `dirp_array` pointer is now `NULL`, ie does not point to any array. You want to store `NULL` to an element in the caller's array, and you do that by the 2nd version above, dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: after modify，i want to get the two-dimensionalh which i have defined.
**

Comment: **
void chack_array(char **array)
{
 while(array != NULL){
  printf("%s\n",(* array));
  array ++;
 }
}
**
and in main()
**
     char *dirp_array[256];
 list_dir(dirp_array);
 chack_array(dirp_array);
**
but it have core dump.

Comment: @haochenghhc note that your `dirp_array` is not two-dimensional array. it is array of pointers (which point to pointers to char). You could also have two-dimensional array of char, which would be quite different thing, even if you can index it with same `foo[row][column]` syntax. C arrays and pointers, and especially mixing them, are rather a complicated subject, and passing arrays to functions is even more complicated.